# Giving materials something to reflect while still having transparent background?

Tags: transparency, reflection

I'm modelling 3D objects against transparent backgrounds, so I can render to 2D images (from different camera angles, or animated) and use in a game.

So I want the background to be transparent.

Yet I sometimes want to use glossy materials that "reflect" the "environment", even though I don't want the environment to actually be visible in the background.

That is to say, I want a background that is visible when reflected on objects, but not visible behind the object.

Is this doable?

Answer (score 2):

You can separate the lighting and reflections from the background image provided by an HDRI by using the *Is Camera Ray* output of a *Light Path* node as a mix factor for a *Mix Shader* combining the original HDRI image with whatever other background you want (although black is the most "invisible" you can get - transparency cannot be achieved this way):

[image: SPlit]

If you want the background truly transparent, check *Transparent* under *Render Properties > Film*:

[image: TransBack]